# How to express past time in some place

Tags: past-tense, expressions

I am trying to write the acknowledgment section of my thesis.  I am trying to say that I have been in this place (the country where I am doing my thesis) for three years.

How to express this:

1. It has been almost three years in XXXX
2. It is almost three years in XXXX
3. Almost three years has been passed in XXXX

I am not sure which form is correct (may be none of them).
Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You can make yourself the subject:

> I have been here in ____________ for nearly three years.

or you can make the years the subject:

> Nearly three years have passed since I came to ______________.

or you can make the country the subject:

> ________________ has been my home for the past three years.